# Clone a model for shadow table

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, mvvm

I have an ASP.NET Core C# application with MVVM pattern.
I have a viewModel coming back from a View into the Controller.
Before processing it, I need to create save the data in the viewModel into a "shadow" table with the same details as the production table.  Some foreign keys are not specified in the shadow table.

Do I create a copy of the prod viewModel as shadowViewModel and do the DBContext.Add or Update or is there a better way of doing it?

If I need to create the shadowViewModel, how do I do that?  There's like 134 fields so I don't want to map each one.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clone your viewModel, you can use `Binary Serializer Clone`.

For example:

Model ( The `[Serializable]` attribute must be added ) :

```
[Serializable]
public class ViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public ViewModel Clone()
    {
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            formatter.Serialize(stream, this);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return (ViewModel)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel();
    viewModel.Id = 1;
    viewModel.Name = "Name";
    viewModel.Title = "Title";
    var TestModel = (ViewModel)viewModel.Clone();
    return View();
}
```

.csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization>true</EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Test Result:

[image]

Hope this can help you.